# How can I make reflection faster?

Tags: .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “cost” of .NET reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224232/what-is-the-cost-of-net-reflection)

I'm a little surprised this exact question hasn't been asked here before (that I've found).  But like the title says: How to make reflection faster?

Comment: Use it less? But you will need to provide a question a bit more specific if you would like this to survive, most likely.

Comment: acquire a better processor ???

Comment: If you could not find a similar question, you clearly have not searched hard enough.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I use reflection to load data I retrieve from sql server into my business objects and I can load the data 'into' the business objects as fast as smss does a select * on the same table.

Comment: @Umer Yes, but what processor is going to speed it up by over 500x? :)

Comment: @BrianRoach Hardly.  I didn't ask what the cost was, I asked how to reduce the cost.

Comment: @leppie I've searched quite a bit actually.  I just wanted to share my findings with a lot of people who will appreciate it so I posed the question in order to do that.

Comment: You could also add your answer to one of the duplicate posts.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Just did, as a comment.  Didn't find them until they were pointed out to me though because I wasn't searching for quite the right thing.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Which tells me that someone else who's searching for how to make it faster rather than asking how bad it is may not find those articles either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an api like fasterflect: http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/ or learn (from same website) the tools you need to speed it up yourself.