# Can you read annotations by walking an object tree

Tags: c#, annotations

Considering the following code, is there a way to walk the object tree and determine all the methods with progress, their weight and an overall cost?

let's say I have a custom annotation:

```
public enum ProgressWeight
  {
    ExtraLight,
    Light,
    Medium,
    Heavy,
    ExtraHeavy
  }

  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class Progressable : Attribute
  {
    public ProgressWeight Weight { get; set; }

    public Progressable(ProgressWeight weight)
    {
      this.Weight = weight;
    }
  }
```

And I want to implement it as such:

```
public class Sumathig
{
  Foo CompositionObject;

  [Progressable(ProgressWeight.Light)]
  public void DoSomethingLight()
  {
    \\Do something that takes little time
  }

  [Progressable(ProgressWeight.ExtraHeavy)]
  public void DoSomeIntesiveWork()
  {
    CompositionObject = new Foo();
    CompositionObject.DoWork();
    CompositionObject.DoMoreWork();
  }
}

class Foo
{
  [Progressable(ProgressWeight.Medium)]
  public void DoWork()
  {
    \\Do some work
  }

  [Progressable(ProgressWeight.Heavy)]
  public void DoSomeMoreWork()
  {
    \\Do more work
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this if you either iterate over an array of the `Type`s of the classes or `Expression`s of the methods involved... It seems a bit messy though.

Comment: The `annotation` is the wrong word in this case. Fix tag. They are `attributes`.

Comment: If you have information about `type`(metadata) then you have information all you need. Use reflection.

Comment: He knows how to access the metadata most likely, what he wanted was to walk the class tree. I don't think that's possible unless you use something like Roslyn.

Comment: if I have to use a compiler than it's unlikely I'll go this route. I need to weight methods and present progress via events.

Comment: Again, you can pass methods in expressions and get the information from them that way, or you can do it from the `Type`s that contain them. It isn't that difficult, unless you want it to be arbitrary. That's the only reason you'd use Roslyn.

Comment: does anyone know anything about interceptors and events via ioc?

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1 - Annotations**

The example you provided suggests that you should take a look at:

- [MSDN: Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)
- [MSDN: Creating Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx)

This approach enables you to annotate your code with meta data which is retrievable at run-time.  The entire process is relatively straight forward.  For an example of reflection, take a look at:

- [CodeProject: Reflection in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET)

**ADDITIONAL READING**

- [O'Reilly: Programming in C# (by: Jesse Liberty)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html)
- [What is the “cost” of .NET reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224232/what-is-the-cost-of-net-reflection)

**OPTION 2**

An alternative approach is to favor composition and expose the required meta data as a property on one of your classes.  This might work well for a *plug-in* style architecture.