# Object Auditing using reflection

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

its me again! :)

I've been tasked with creating a system to auditing out internal objects, my first iteration was no flexible and very slow so I'm hoping to rewrite it and really make it work how it should.

Performance for this needs to be as perfect as possible, the auditing code is probably going to be run on every object in our system when they are saved..

This code below is what I've done so far - I've profiled it using the visual studio tools and I think I've remove quite a few possible performance hits along the way..

What I really want from you guys is to review this and suggest any possible improvements, Its also worth nothing that **CreateObjectFromHistory** method doesn't need to be as performant as the rest, its barely going to ever get called.

Also - they keyvaluepair saving is out of my hands.

Any help would be brilliant..

Cheers :)

//Wall o-code coming up..

```
    public static void AuditObject(ITraceable obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return;

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = GetPropertyInfo(obj);

        List<SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object>> kvpList =
            new List<SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object>>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object> thisValue = new SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object>();

            thisValue.Key = property.Name;

            thisValue.Value = GetPropertyValue(obj, property);

            if (thisValue.Value != null)
                kvpList.Add(thisValue);
        }

        TestObject o = CreateObjectFromHistory<TestObject>(kvpList);
    }

    public static T CreateObjectFromHistory<T>(List<SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object>> history)
        where T : class, ITraceable
    {
        T historicalObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertys = GetPropertysAsDictionary(historicalObject);

        foreach (SerializeableKeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in history)
        {
            if (!propertys.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                continue;

            PropertyInfo prop = propertys[kvp.Key];

            if (prop == null)
                continue;

            var value = CoerceValue(prop.PropertyType, kvp.Value);

            prop.SetValue(historicalObject, value, null);

        }

        return historicalObject;

    }

    private static object CoerceValue(Type type, object value)
    {
        if (type == typeof(string))
            return value as string;

        return null;
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue(ITraceable obj, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            return GetProperyValueByType<string>(property.GetValue(obj, null));
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            return GetProperyValueByType<DateTime>(property.GetValue(obj, null));

        return null;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(ITraceable obj)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> properties;

        Type objType = obj.GetType();

        if (PropertyDictionary.TryGetValue(objType, out properties) == false)
        {
            properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                     BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();

            properties.RemoveAll(p => IgnoreProperty(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNoTraceAttribute), false)));

            PropertyDictionary.Add(objType, properties);
        }

        return properties;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> GetPropertysAsDictionary(ITraceable obj)
    {
        return GetPropertyInfo(obj).ToDictionary(pro => pro.Name);
    }

    private static object GetProperyValueByType<T>(object value)
    {
        T actualType = (T)value;

        if (actualType.Equals(default(T)))
            return default(T);

        //this will need further implementation

        return (T)value;
    }

    private static bool IgnoreProperty(IEnumerable<object> p)
    {
        return p.AsParallel().OfType<DoNoTraceAttribute>().Any();
    }
```

Updated Code;

```
   private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(ITraceable obj)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> properties;

        Type objType = obj.GetType();

        if (PropertyDictionary.TryGetValue(objType, out properties) == false)
        {
            properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                     BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();

            properties.RemoveAll(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DoNoTraceAttribute)));

            PropertyDictionary.Add(objType, properties);
        }

        return properties;
    }
```

Do this look better ?

Comment: It *looks* like `CoerceValue` means your code only works *at all* with strings....?

Comment: Does the parallel instruction improve performance in your scenario or does it make it worse?

Comment: Yeah - at the moment CoerceValue is only working with strings, this eventually is only going to work with strings, datetime, bit and guids.

Comment: Also - Parallel did increase the performance.. very slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` at runtime, the performance will always be slow. To get good performance (especially for looking at lots of objects) you will need to look at something like `ILGenerator` or `Expression` - or you could just use something like [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) and access the values via `prop.Name`. I really do not think `IgnoreProperty` is implemented well - you should just look at `Attribute.IsDefined` here; no need for LINQ, no need for `Parallel`, and no need to materialize the attributes.

Comment: could you please provide a sample using FastMember? Also - see updates.

Comment: @Stephen - fastmember - this do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771524/how-slow-is-reflection/771533#771533 Note that there is also `ObjectAccessor`, if you aren't always dealing with blocks of the same type. It worries about caching per type etc internally, so you don't have to. That `Attribute.IsDefined` usage looks much better.

Comment: That looks great - im going to try it now.. How much quicker is your Fastmember ususaly than they way im currently doing it?

Comment: @Stephen numbers are here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html (see "Mary Mary quite contrary...")