# asp.net Entity framework database insertion using loop through columns Using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I have a table named `Variables` which has `(Id ,AdId,Variable1,Variable2,Variable3,Variable4,Variable5,Variable6,Variable7,Variable8 )`
, and I have a `List<string> a` which contains a number of strings (maybe 1,3,6,or 8).

My question is how to insert these strings in the List to the Variables table?

I can do such a thing

```
    Variables v=new Variables();
    v.AdId=2;

if(a.count()==1){

v.variable1=a[0];
}else if(a.count()==2){
v.variable1=a[0];
v.variable2=a[1]
}else if (//so on){}
```

But

I want to do something more dynamically  like so:

```
Variables v=new Variables();
    v.AdId=2;
    for(int i=0; i<a.count() ;i++)
    {
         //here list items to be inserted to (variable1,variable2.....variable8)
         //, depending on list size ,number of variables are inserted
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection/) to access the properties of the Variable model dynamically using the **GetProperty** method.

```
        Variables v = new Variables();
        var a = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            String propertyName = "Variable" + i;
            Type myType = v.GetType();
            try
            {
                myType.GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(v, a[i].ToString());
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException nre)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot Find Property");
            }
        }
```

As you can see I access the property of the object using the string `propertyName` so you could manipulate that string in such a way that it access the property you want to modify.

I used a try and catch block in the end if the property we are trying to access is not defined in the class / model.

Also take note that Reflection can be a slow solution. You can look for ways to improve it's performance drastically though.

Thanks. Hope that helps.

Comment: WOOOOW , Worked ! 
, That was exactly what I was desiring , thank you for your Answer (You genius)

Comment: But @Andrei why its slow?

Comment: I believe it is slow because Reflection checks the metadata and if you use reflection a lot it will be relatively slower than normal property assignments. You could check this link to help you understand the trade-offs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771524/how-slow-is-reflection

Answer (score 2):

You can try below as a sample when using Linq to entities. For adding Column values later you can use as an option a factory method called `CreateT`, where `T` is the name of the 
entity class.

Now since your `List<string>` can have variable number of items,  Entity class doesn't has a dynamic way to get Columns like: `Variables.Columns[i]` OR `Variables["ColumnName"]`. So using any loop is feasible but still you need to check all the values from `a[1]` to `a[9]`.

I'm assuming that the `List<string> a` contains values in sequence. i.e `a[1]` contains the corresponding value for Column: `AdId` etc..

```
 NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
    Variables vrbl = Variables.CreateVariables(a[0]);// usually have atleast one value 
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[1]))
    AdId = a[1]; 
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[2]))
    Variable1= a[2]; // assign the corresponding values from List of strings 
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[3]))
    Variable2= a[3];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[4])) 
    Variable3= a[4];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[5])) 
    Variable4= a[5];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[6]))
    Variable5= a[6];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[7])) 
    Variable6= a[7];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[8])) 
    Variable7= a[8];
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a[9])) 
    Variable8= a[9];

    db.Variables.AddObject(vrbl); 
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yes Its correct but sometimes I may have 2 list items, some times 3, til 8 , how to deal with this case , do I have to take all possibilities? or there is some dynamic thing , like looping throw table colomns!

Comment: The Dynamic options aren't available much with EF, You can check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this.For fast rply.. may be dirty solution

You can use the switch case statement.

```
Variables v=new Variables();
v.AdId=2;
for(int i=0; i<a.count() ;i++)
{
switch (a.count())
    { 
        case 0:
            v.Variable1 = a[i].ToString();
            break;
        case 1:
            v.Variable1 = a[i].ToString();
            v.Variable2 = a[i++].ToString();
         case 2:
            v.Variable1 = a[i].ToString();
            v.Variable2 = a[i++].ToString();
            v.Variable2 = a[i+2].ToString();
            break;

and so on.....

    }
}
```

Comment: I think of something more dynamically

Comment: Yes you are right , but this time I have take all 8 possibilities , is there any shorter way?? cause I need this technique alot

Comment: In this way I have to take all 8 possibilities , is there any shorter and more dynamic way?

Answer (score 1):

You can write [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) for you Variables class. But inner implementation have to use either switch or reflection for setting value to property.