# How to "clone" an object into a subclass object?

Tags: c#, object, copy, subclass

I have a class `A` and a class `B` that inherits class `A` and extends it with some more fields.

Having an object `a` of type `A`, how can I create an object `b` of type `B` that contains all data that object `a` contained?

I have tried `a.MemberwiseClone()` but that only gives me another type `A` object. And I cannot cast `A` into `B` since the inheritance relationship only allows the opposite cast.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was looking for an automatic way to this but you're suggesting there's no such. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  You'll need to add a constructor or a factory method of some form.

Comment: @Vizu which method did you adopt, i also want something similar, please put here if you have it

Comment: @ARUN I did what the accepted answer suggests but I would give a try to the most upvoted answer too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no means of doing this automatically built into the language...

One option is to add a constructor to class B that takes a class A as an argument.

Then you could do:

```
B newB = new B(myA);
```

The constructor can just copy the relevant data across as needed, in that case.

Comment: is it possible to , copy a sub class to super class having some of the similar feilds

Answer (score 11):

I would add a copy constructor to A, and then add a new constructor to B that takes an instance of A and passes it to the base's copy constructor.

Comment: The accepted answer is what I've always done, but this twist is simple and elegant.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using reflection.

**Advantage:** Maintainability. No need for changing copy-constructor or similar, adding or removing properties.

**Disadvantage**: Performance. Reflection is slow. We're still talking milliseconds on average sized classes though.

Here's a reflection-based shallow copy implementation supporting copy-to-subclass, using extension methods:

```
public static TOut GetShallowCopyByReflection<TOut>(this Object objIn) 
{
    Type inputType = objIn.GetType();
    Type outputType = typeof(TOut);
    if (!outputType.Equals(inputType) && !outputType.IsSubclassOf(inputType)) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} is not a sublcass of {1}", outputType, inputType));
    PropertyInfo[] properties = inputType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    FieldInfo[] fields = inputType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    TOut objOut = (TOut)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TOut));
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        try
        {
            property.SetValue(objOut, property.GetValue(objIn, null), null);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException) { } // For Get-only-properties
    }
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        field.SetValue(objOut, field.GetValue(objIn));
    }
    return objOut;
}
```

This method will copy all properties - private and public, as well as all fields. Properties are copied by reference, making it a shallow copy.

Unit tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class ExtensionTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetShallowCloneByReflection_PropsAndFields()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        var source = new TestClassParent();
        source.SomePublicString = "Pu";
        source.SomePrivateString = "Pr";
        source.SomeInternalString = "I";
        source.SomeIntField = 6;
        source.SomeList = new List<Uri>() { uri };

        var dest = source.GetShallowCopyByReflection<TestClassChild>();
        Assert.AreEqual("Pu", dest.SomePublicString);
        Assert.AreEqual("Pr", dest.SomePrivateString);
        Assert.AreEqual("I", dest.SomeInternalString);
        Assert.AreEqual(6, dest.SomeIntField);
        Assert.AreSame(source.SomeList, dest.SomeList);
        Assert.AreSame(uri, dest.SomeList[0]);            
    }
}

internal class TestClassParent
{
    public String SomePublicString { get; set; }
    internal String SomeInternalString { get; set; }
    internal String SomePrivateString { get; set; }
    public String SomeGetOnlyString { get { return "Get"; } }
    internal List<Uri> SomeList { get; set; }
    internal int SomeIntField;
}

internal class TestClassChild : TestClassParent {}
```

Comment: What counts as average class size?

Comment: @adam-l-s Hehe good question. My answer as always when it comes to performance: Measure. If it's fast enough for you, use it. Reflection is said to be 1000 times slower than accessing properties the normal way though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection

Comment: I know this is a six year old answer, but there is a bug in the code. The line that says:
`property.SetValue(objIn, property.GetValue(objIn, null), null);`
should be:
`property.SetValue(objOut, property.GetValue(objIn, null), null);`
Otherwise the properties are just set back on the original object and not the new object. Just trying to help out some copy-pasters out there.

Comment: I note that the performance issues can be eliminated completely if you're comfortable with `Reflection.Emit` to generate a clone method on-demand.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
    private abstract class A
    {
        public int P1 { get; set; }

        public abstract A CreateInstance();

        public virtual A Clone()
        {
            var instance = CreateInstance();
            instance.P1 = this.P1;
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private class B : A
    {
        public int P2 { get; set; }

        public override A CreateInstance()
        {
            return new B();
        }

        public override A Clone()
        {
            var result = (B) base.Clone();
            result.P2 = P2;
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B() { P1 = 111, P2 = 222 };

        var c = b.Clone();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ctor in B that allows one to pass in an object of type A, then copy the A fields and set the B fields as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Convert method on class B that takes in the base class.

```
public ClassB Convert(ClassA a)
{
   ClassB b = new ClassB();
   // Set the properties
   return b;
}
```

You could also have a constructor for ClassB take in an object of ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. One way to achieve this is to add a constructor on class B that accepts a parameter of type B, and add data manually.

So you could have something like this:

```
public class B
{
  public B(A a)
  {
    this.Foo = a.foo;
    this.Bar = a.bar;
    // add some B-specific data here
  }
}
```

Comment: I disagree that you should have a Clone() method on A that returns a B, as this introduces a circular dependency.

Comment: I agree with the constructor for class B, but why do you need the CloneToB() method?

Comment: ehm yeah you're right, I shouldn't have included that method. I included it because the poster mentioned MemberWiseClone(). Anyway, this code is not good and I will delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your base class add the CreateObject virtual method below...

```
    public virtual T CreateObject<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(this.GetType()))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(this.GetType().ToString() + " does not inherit from " + typeof(T).ToString());
        }

        T ret = System.Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        PropertyInfo[] propTo = ret.GetType().GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] propFrom = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        // for each property check whether this data item has an equivalent property
        // and copy over the property values as neccesary.
        foreach (PropertyInfo propT in propTo)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propF in propFrom)
            {
                if (propT.Name == propF.Name)
                {
                    propF.SetValue(ret,propF.GetValue(this));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

then say you want to create a real life subclass object from the super class just call

```
this.CreateObject<subclass>();
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

While no one suggested this (and this won't work for everyone, admittedly), it should be said that if you have the option of creating object b from the get-go, do that instead of creating object a then copying to object b. For example, imagine that you are in the same function and have this code:

```
var a = new A();
a.prop1 = "value";
a.prop2 = "value";
...
// now you need a B object instance...
var b = new B();
// now you need to copy a into b...
```

Instead of worrying about that last commented step, just start with b and set the values:

```
var b = new B();
b.prop1 = "value";
b.prop2 = "value";
```

I appreciate that not everyone will like the above. I have encountered many programmers who are so focused on their code that they didn't realize a simpler solution is staring them in the face. :)

Answer (score -1):

here's a way that worked for me using a constructor:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self, **attrs):
        self.__dict__.update(**attrs)
        ...

b = ClassA(**other_class.__dict__)
```

can also work with inheritance

```
class Fields(AbstractType):
    def __init__(self, **attrs):
        self.__dict__.update(**attrs)

    my_date = Field(Date, required=True)
    text_field = Field(String, required=True)
    ...

class MyClass(InputObjectType, Fields):
    pass


class MyClassWithError(ObjectType, Fields):
    error = Field(String, required=True)


error_class = MyClassWithError(**my_class.__dict__)
error_class.error = "my error description"
```