# Copying over information from parent object into child object

Tags: c#

So I have a parent entity `Producer` and its child `ProducerNS`.

`ProducerNS` inherited all the properties of `Producer` and an additional field, lets call that `anyColumn`

I have an object Producer and I want to copy over the object into ProducerNS like so,

```
Producer producer = getproducer();
ProducerNS producerns = producer;
producerns.anyColumn = 'hellobunnies';
```

However, I know the above syntax is incorrect. Can I transfer over all the properties without doing so individually? (Producer has a lot of fields) If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want without manually implementing copy constructor is to have your `getproducer()` function to become generic:

```
T getproducer<T>()
   where T : Producer, new()
{
    var result = new T();
    ...
    return result;
}

...

ProducerNS producerns = getproducer<ProduceNS>();
producerns.anyColumn = 'hellobunnies';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a deep copy of your producer object into your producerns object.

Have a look here for ideas for doing a deep copy in c#, keep in mind that your subclass obviously has your additional property which you will need to take into consideration: [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

here is a post specifically for subclass copying: [How to "clone" an object into a subclass object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093056/how-to-clone-an-object-into-a-subclass-object)

Another option would be to use reflection to get a list of properties from your producer object and use the values of each property in your producerns object. This could be done in a simple foreach loop