# Smoothing the results of a series server-side to return fewer data points (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

I need to show a chart from data returned from an API.

This API could potentially return millions of results, but it would tax the server heavily.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to return a fewer number of results and still show a trend in the chart. Basically, I'm looking to "smooth" the line of the graph by showing only relevant points.

Is there a .NET library that could help me in this implementation? Or perhaps a "smoothing" function that takes a limit on the number of points to results?

Answer (score 1):

What would be your target number of results? One approach would be to just take a sampling of the points. For every 10 points you have, return 1, for instance. In which case, you could use Linq to accomplish this: [Sampling a list with linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439658/sampling-a-list-with-linq)

This doesn't address the "showing only relevant points" part of your question, though. That's a little harder to solve programmatically. What does "relevant" mean in your data? Exceeding a certain deviation?

So maybe a moving average of your data would work. Take 10 points at a time, average them, return 1 point. Like this example: [Smoothing data from a sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611599/smoothing-data-from-a-sensor)

With either of those approaches, you can trade off accuracy and 'smoothness' by varying the "10" in the above examples. The higher the number, the "smoother" your result.