# Example : Speeding up Reflection API with delegate in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

As is asked in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430479/speeding-up-reflection-api-with-delegate-in-net-c/6430561#6430561), I came up with an example that uses Delegate to speedup Refection in .NET/C#.

However, I got this error when running (compilation works fine). What might be wrong?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: type is not a subclass of Multicastdelegate
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure, Boolean allowClosed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at EX.RefTest.DelegateTest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at EX.RefTest.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

### ADDED

This is the (working) source code thanks to the help from Jon & ChaosPandion.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System;

namespace EX
{
    public class Hello
    {
        // properties
        public int Valx {get; set;}
        public int Valy {get; set;}
        public Hello()
        {
            Valx = 10; Valy = 20;
        }
        public int Sum(int x, int y)
        {
            Valx = x; Valy = y;
            return (Valx + Valy);
        }
    }
    public class RefTest
    {
        static void DelegateTest()
        {
            Hello h = new Hello();
            Type type = h.GetType();
            MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("Sum");

            // Wrong! Delegate call = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, m);
            Delegate call = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), h, m);
            int res = (int) call.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {100, 200});
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", res);
            // This is a direct method implementation from Jon's post, and this is much faster
            Func<int, int, int> sum = (Func<int, int, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), h, m);
            res = sum(100, 200);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", res);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            DelegateTest();
        }
    }
}
```

### ADDED2

Based on Jon's answer, I did some performance test to use sum 1000 time.
Compared to the method of using `(int) call.DynamicInvoke(new object[] {100, 200});`, `Func<int, int, int> sum = (Func<int, int, int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), h, m);` is 300 times faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Hello` isn't a delegate type - so you can't pass it into `Delegate.CreateDelegate` as the first argument. You need a delegate type with the same parameter types and return type - in this case, something like:

```
delegate int Foo(int x, int y);
```

or

```
Func<int, int, int>
```

Also note that the overload of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` you've called is meant to be used for a *static* method - you ought to be using the overload which also takes the target of the delegate (in this case, `h`).

I have a [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates) which shows using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` for speeding up access. Note that I wouldn't expect `DynamicInvoke` to be significantly faster than calling the method directly with reflection... it's still going to have to check the parameter types etc. Really you want a strongly-typed delegate type called statically (as opposed to dynamically) to make things really fast.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of delegate and bind the `this` parameter.

```
Delegate call = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>), h, m);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have also used:

```
m.Invoke(null, new object[] { 100, 200 });
```

It doesn't cause any performance issues from what I've been dealing with.