# Slow Invoke, DynamicInvoke and Func<>

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to use `WindowsAPICodePack` function `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.TaskbarProgressBarState.SetProgressValue` .
It works, but is very slow. Normally it takes about 20-30 ms, but with this method it increases to about 180-190 ms for one call.
I heard that [calling a method by reflection is about 1000 times slower than calling it normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection/29599#29599), so i searched for a way to speed things up.

Initially, i had this:

```
//class constructor
asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll");
type = asm.GetType("Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.TaskbarManager");
classInstance = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);

progressBarValueMethod = type.GetMethod("SetProgressValue", new Type[2]{typeof(int), typeof(int)});

//class method
progressBarValueMethod.Invoke(classInstance, new object[2]{val * 10, max * 10});
```

I tried to speed it by changing this:

```
//class contructor
progressBarValueMethod = type.GetMethod("SetProgressValue", new Type[2]{typeof(int), typeof(int)});

//class method
progressBarValueMethod.Invoke(classInstance, new object[2] { val * 10, max * 10 });
```

to this:

```
//class constructor
progressBarValueMethod = type.GetMethod("SetProgressValue", new Type[2]{typeof(int), typeof(int)});
progressBarStateMethodDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>), classInstance, progressBarValueMethod);

//class method
progressBarStateMethodDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new object[2] { val * 10, max * 10 });
```

but it didn't work. Calling this method still took about 180 ms.
I found another solution, so I changed the code again:

```
//class constructor
progressBarValueMethod = type.GetMethod("SetProgressValue", new Type[2]{typeof(int), typeof(int)});
delegateFunc = (Func<int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>), classInstance, progressBarValueMethod);

//class method
delegateFunc(val * 10, max * 10);
```

which changed nothing. Solid 180 ms.
Is there a different way to speed it?
By the way, I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason for you to use dynamic invoke. That's more for when you have a collection of delegates and the one you're invoking isn't known at compile time. The other snippets likely all become the same IL.

Comment: Also the cost isn't in the Invoke statement, GetMethod is the thing using reflection. Invoking the delegate is much like invoking a function from a function pointer in C/C++, not a costly operation.

Comment: Have you tried Activator.CreateInstance(type)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal not quite - `MethodInfo.Invoke` is still very slow; it is only once it has been converted to a **typed** delegate that you have a fast invoke

Comment: can you show how you are timing this? 180ms sounds *very* long - is this perhaps first-time performance (fusion, JIT, etc)? of course, it could just be that it *takes this long*. How many times are you calling `delegateFunc(...)` for you test? vs how many times doing all the reflection overhead of finding the method and creating the typed delegate etc

Comment: @terrybozzio I can't, because `TaskBarManager` doesn't have any constructor.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using it for showing progress of picture converting; calling every time it passes one line of it (so hundreds of times). Reflection overhead is called once, only function under `//class method` comment is called many times (`Invoke`, `DynamicInvoke` or `delegateFunc`).

Comment: @Thomas your question is interesting, but your reporting timings are odd. Your last example is pretty much what I would have suggested to do here - once you have a typed delegate it *should* be very fast. I know the CLR team have spent a lot of time making this faster between versions, but it should be plenty fast in 2.0. Your timings are... Unusual

Comment: @MarcGravell
Here's what I do.  
Constructor:  
    `public delegate void Func<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);  
    Func<int, int> delegateFunc = (Func<int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int>), classInstance, progressBarValueMethod);`
  
And method:  
    `public void setValue(int val, int max = 100)
    {
 if (!pBarSupported) return;
 delegateFunc(val * 10, max * 10);
    }`
  
Time for 512 `setValue` calls is 180 ms. Without it - 25.