# PropertyInfo getValue works so slow

Tags: .net, entity-framework, propertyinfo

```
PropertyInfo info =currentobject.getType.getproperty (propertychain)
currentobject=info.getvalue (currentobject)
```

When I put a string instead of getValue it works pretty fast. But if it returns an object it gets so slow?

Why is that, is there a possible solution/workaround for this?

Comment: The work around is probably to work out if you really need reflection, removing reflection is almost guarranteed to speed up whatever you are trying to solve

Comment: This won't compile - can you correct it to C# ?

Comment: Don't use reflection, if you can avoid it. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running this method on a relatively small number of classes you could cache references to property getters to remove some reflection overhead.