# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[ModelName]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

My Entityframework context :

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }        
}
```

My method to add objects:

```
public void AddObject(DbContext context, Type t, object object_to_add)
{      
     PropertyInfo context_property = 
            context.GetType().GetProperties()
           .Where(p => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)
                       && p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Any()
                       && p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First() == t)
           .Single();

     DbSet db_set = (DbSet)context_property.GetMethod.Invoke(context, null);

     db_set.Add(object_to_add);
}
```

But the code crashes when I try to cast a `DbSet<>` to `DbSet`,

I'm using reflection because I receive DTO objects that I map to an existing model(via reflection as well), I don't want to code an add method for each new model (I have like 40 and the list is exponentially growing)

Blockquote

Any solution?

Comment: Is your context and this code in the same assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reflection in a production environment will yield a poor performance. So **octaviocci**'s method is better in every way.

However if you cannot make your method generic, you can try

```
public void AddObject(DbContext context, Type t, object object_to_add)
{
   context.Set(t).Add(object_to_add);
}
```

You are getting `InvalidCastException` because
`System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>` does not implement `System.Data.Entity.DbSet`.

See the definition on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, 
    IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

Comment: Any serializer/parser uses reflection, don't you use one? and yes I use reflection in production, works like a charm takes 1second for 140 classes (1000 objects), 90% of the code elimintaed, just index you objects.

Comment: @Akli I also included another a not-generic solution.

Comment: See this post about performance impact of reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection. IMHO it is best to avoid it as long as possible.

Comment: BTW you are right, most of the serializers use reflection. But they at least try to cache the reflection information.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted ;) and +1 for everyone

Answer (score 7):

I think is easier if you create a generic method:

```
public void AddObject<T>(DbContext context,  T object_to_add)
{
   context.Set<T>().Add(object_to_add);
}
```

Yo can use [`Set<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) method as I show above.

Comment: That will force me to use this ugly code : GetMethod("AddObject").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(this, new object[] { context,  object_to_add});

Comment: Anyway I'll accept your answer if there isn't another solution

Comment: To avoid invoke that method by reflection i would use dependency injection instead. You can use, eg, some patterns like Repository and UnitOfWork, all represented with interfaces, Later using DI you can provide an implementation of those interfaces and invoke the proper method pretty similar as I show above, avoiding the ugly code using reflection. This [codeplex project](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) could be a good start